# gdb memory usage for huge coredumps

Tags: linux, gdb, coredump

When opening a coredump with gdb, will gdb try to load the full coredump into memory?

I've found a coredump with a size of 35Gb on one of our staging systems. Our operating instructions call for the creation of a backtrace using gdb. I'm afraid gdb will try to load the full coredump into memory and render the staging area unusable by using up all available memory.

We're using gdb 7.0.1 on a RedHat EL 5 / 64bit installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When opening a coredump with gdb, will gdb try to load the full coredump into memory?

No.

> I'm afraid gdb will try to load the full coredump into memory and render the staging area unusable by using up all available memory.

Even without loading the entire core dump, GDB *will* consume some memory, so you *may* have an effect on your staging system. If you can't afford to have an effect, then you need to modify your "operating procedures", e.g. move the core to a different system and analyze it there. Beware: *if* your executable uses dynamic linking, you must arrange for the dynamic libraries to match *exactly* at the time when core dump was generated and when it is analyzed.

Comment: Is there a way to estimate how much memory gdb will consume? Running gdb with coredumps up to 4Gb has never been a problem in this environment. Unfortunately I've never bothered to check how much memory was used.

Comment: "Beware: if your executable uses dynamic linking, you must arrange for the dynamic libraries to match exactly at the time when core dump was generated and when it is analyzed." what happens if they aren't?  Will the backtrace, at least, be present?

Comment: "what happens if they aren't?" It depends. If you don't catch the signal (e.g. to print a message), and the crash happens *not* in the system library, they you likely will get a stack trace. Otherwise, you likely will get a truncated stack trace, or just garbage.